# Cannot find module 'worker_threads' error in production

Tags: node.js, typescript, runtime-error, worker

I created a node js project that utilizes worker threads. The code works fine when I run npm start in VS Code. But when build and copied in Ubuntu server, it show "Cannot find module 'worker_threads'".

Is there additional configuration that must be done when deploying node js with worker threads in production? By the way here how I deploy it in Ubuntu server.

1.) since my project is typecript, I compiled it using 'tsc' command
2.) the 'tsc' command produced 'build' folder
3.) I copied the package.json and package-lock.json into the 'build' folder
4.) zip the 'build' folder and transfer to Ubuntu server using 'scp' command
5.) in Ubuntu server, I unzip the the 'build' folder
6.) I run 'npm install' in the 'build' folder to download dependencies
7.) I the run my program with 'node ./src/main.js' and also 'pm2 start ./src/main/js' to no avail

Other projects without the worker threads deployed without problem using above procedure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using on the Ubuntu server?

Comment: I was getting this error when running `yarn install` on windows for git sdk minggw on windows, but when I switched to using the normal git for windows shell it went away. git for windows has two versions - normal git bash, and an sdk version which comes with more features.

Answer (score 34):

Maybe your node.js version is below 12.x. Workers are supported after 10.5.
Try adding this to your package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-worker ./src/main.js"
}
```

Comment: I had older nodejs version on Ubuntu 2004 - I remove version installed by apt and installed latest nodejs using snap

Comment: I upgraded(to 19.x.x) node version(though the version I was on was 10.19.0) and it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In my Glitch site, I was able to fix this problem by adding this to my package.json:

```
  "engines": { "node": "16.x" }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved switching from node 10.16.2 to 16.13.2 (with nvm node version manager).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved by updating my NodeJs to the latest version.

Ref: https://github.com/jlooper/olympic-app/issues/1