# How do I serve my javascript app locally on Linux Mint

Tags: javascript, npm, localhost

I'm currently following a tutorial, and I've made sure to follow each and every step. I'm trying to locally host my javascript app at localhost:3000. However, I'm unable to do so, and whenever I try to run `npm run dev` I get the following error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v10.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle personalwebsite@0.0.0~predev: personalwebsite@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle personalwebsite@0.0.0~dev: personalwebsite@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle personalwebsite@0.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle personalwebsite@0.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/omar-backup/Desktop/MrBoogle.github.io/personalWebsite/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
9 verbose lifecycle personalwebsite@0.0.0~dev: CWD: /home/omar-backup/Desktop/MrBoogle.github.io/personalWebsite
10 silly lifecycle personalwebsite@0.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'vite' ]
11 silly lifecycle personalwebsite@0.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle personalwebsite@0.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: personalwebsite@0.0.0 dev: `vite`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid personalwebsite@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/omar-backup/Desktop/MrBoogle.github.io/personalWebsite
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-26-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v10.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error personalwebsite@0.0.0 dev: `vite`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the personalwebsite@0.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've spent about an hour now trying to figure this out but have yet to find anything. I installed vite but nothing gets hosted (I'm trying to host my app on localhost:3000) and instead a weird window pops up using qt5ct. Unfortunately that no longer works because I probably messed something up while trying to get this to work.
The tutorial I'm following can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7AOvWpIVHU). I'm running into issues around the [2:45](https://youtu.be/Q7AOvWpIVHU?t=166) mark.

Comment: On the directory, add the following previous step before running "npm run dev":
"npm install"
Then try again with npm run dev.
Did it work?

Comment: @IgnacioAcuña nope, didn't work. Cannot find module 'worker_threads'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a project with npm init, like on the tutorial you've seen, a project from a template with be created at some directory. On your case, you ran:

```
npm init @vitejs/app
```

This command got you a folder with some predefined template of Node.JS, which created a package.json for you, wich have all the dependencies required for that project to being able to work. At your case, for example:

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.3.3"
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is a devDependency call *vite*, which need to be installed to execute the npm script of dev, which translates to *"dev": "vite"*.

When you ran before, the vite dependencie wasnt installed on the project, and that was the reason of the error:

```
error personalwebsite@0.0.0 dev: `vite`
```

When you run npm install, it installed all the required dependencies of package.json. So after you installed the vite dependency with npm install (which will take the package.json definition), it stopped lacking dependencies.

That is why your error change to:

```
 Cannot find module 'worker_threads'
```

This is **other error**, and is probably because you are using and [old version of node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280966/cannot-find-module-worker-threads-error-in-production) (info using node@v10.19.0).
Trying to replicate I encounter the same problem:
[image: Node 10]

But when I update to a newer version (Node 14), it didn't happend. So, [just update your node version](https://nodejs.org/es/about/releases/)

[image: Node 14]

Comment: awesome, this worked! I ran into some other issues because of my npm but I fixed that and updating my node version fixed everything else. Thanks :)